# The type or namespace name 'AutoCompleteEntities2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, sql, reactjs, visual-studio-2017, ssms

I'm following a tutorial how to "Add AutoComplete Textbox In React App"(Reference : https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-add-autocomplete-textbox-in-react-applicati). I followed everything as it is but getting one error as following.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using AutoCompleteCustomers.Models;
namespace AutoComplete.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("Api/autoComplete")]
    public class AutoCompleteController : ApiController
    {
        AutoCompleteEntities2 DB = new AutoCompleteEntities2();
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Countrylist")]
        public object Getrecord()
        {
            var data = DB.cicmpy.ToList();
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting : **"The type or namespace name 'AutoCompleteEntities2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**

In order to correct this I've added a new class with the namespace of 'AutoCompleteEntities2' then it gives me a new error **"'AutoCompleteEntities2' does not contain a definition for 'cicmpy' and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type '' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**

I'm fairly new to C# and currently learning, would really appreciate if anyone can explain the error and guide to correct it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following steps to try to solve your problem.

First, please find your model1.context.cs file in your solution and open it.

As usual, you will get the following similar generated code.(If not, please create the ADO.NET Entity Data Model again  )

```
    namespace WebApplication2.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
        
        public partial class SchoolEntities : DbContext
        {
            public SchoolEntities()
                : base("name=SchoolEntities")
            {
            }
        
            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
            }
        
            public virtual DbSet<TblCountry> TblCountries { get; set; }  // corrspond  in the entity.TblCountries
        }
    }
```

Second, we need to add `WebApplication2.Models` to the `AutoCompleteController` and define the method to convert dbset to list.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class AutoCompleteController : Controller
    {

        SchoolEntities entity = new SchoolEntities();

         [HttpGet]  
         [Route("Countrylist")]
        public object Getrecord()
        {
            var data = entity.TblCountries.ToList();

          return data;  
        }


    }
}
```

You can change the correspond code according to my code. I guess that you should use `using AutoComplete.Models;`.